# Highcharts stacked bar chart Likert scale centering

Tags: highcharts, scale, data-visualization

I am trying to use Highcharts to display a Likert Scale.  The problem I face is how to split neutral answer down the middle of the centerline.

I am comfortable formatting the data but I’m not sure how do achieve this.  At present I have 6 data sets one positive neutral and one negative neutral.  But I’d like to think there is a better way to do this with Highcharts.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[Link to the example](http://statistical-research.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/divergingstacked_h.likert.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can approximate this pretty well using a "[Bar with negative stack](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-negative-stack)".  You'll need to split your center "neutral" data into two series; one for the negative side and one for the positive and then link them together:

```
        series: [{
            name: 'Strongly Disagree',
            data: [-10, -5, -6]
        }, {
            name: 'Disagree',
            data: [-2, -5, -3]
        }, {
            name: 'Neutral',
            data: [-2, -5, -3],
            color: 'gray',
            id: 'neutral'
        },{
            name: 'Strongly Agree',
            data: [5, 1,6]
        },{
            name: 'Agree',
            data: [6, 8, 2]
        },{
            name: 'Neutral',
            data: [2, 5, 3],
            color: 'gray',
            linkedTo: 'neutral'
        }]
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KV5KV/).

[image]